# Wave Equation, is this problem well posed?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am solving $$u_{tt}=4u_{xx}$$ $$u(x,0)=x^2-x$$ $$u_t(x,0)=\cos x$$ $$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$$

I am trying to solve with the method of separable factors. So I am trying to find a equation like $u(x,t)=X(x)\cdot T(t)$. But, I am finding a problem, because if the solution is like this, then $u_t(x,0)=X(x)\cdot T'(0) = \cos x\Rightarrow X(x) = \frac{\cos x}{T'(0)}$.

But if $X(x)$ is this way, then $X(0)=\frac{\cos 0}{T'(0)}\neq 0$.

Am I solving this right or the problem is not well posed?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you only find *one* solution. If we separate $u(x,t)  = X(x)T(t)$ then $T'/T = \lambda$ and  $4X''/X = \lambda$ for some constant $\lambda$ that is determined by the boundary conditions (typically this gives $\lambda$ is a constant times an integer). The full solution is then a linear combination over all the particular solutions given by different $\lambda$-values. $u(x,t) = \sum a_\lambda X_\lambda(x)T_\lambda(t)$. It's *this* solution that equals $x^2-x$. It's the boundary conditions that can be applied on a single solution so $X_\lambda(0) = 0$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separated solutions of $u_{tt}=4u_{xx}$ have the form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ where
$$
               \frac{T''}{T}=\lambda = \frac{X''}{X}
$$

leading to

$$
         T(t) = A\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)+B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}t) \\
         X(x) = C\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+D\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
$$

The condition $X(0)=X(1)=0$ requires $\sqrt{\lambda}=n\pi$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and
$$
        X_n(t)=C_n\sin(n\pi x) \\
        T_n(t)=A_n\cos(n\pi t)+B_n\sin(n\pi t).
$$
The general solution (after combining constants) is
$$
         u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\cos(n\pi t)+B_n\sin(n\pi t))\sin(n\pi x)
$$

The constants are determined by the initial conditions:
$$
       x^2-x = u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x) \\
         \cos(x) = u_t(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n n\pi\sin(n\pi x).
$$
So,
$$
       A_n = \frac{\int_{0}^{1}(x^2-x)\sin(n\pi x)dx}{\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx}, \\
   B_n = \frac{\int_{0}^{1}\cos(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx}{n\pi\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx}.
$$